# Selecting Max Count on another Column

Tags: sql

I've been stuck on trying to come up with a query to GROUP BY CODE, so that CCC for example should only appear once, and also selecting the Name with the highest count. Can someone point me in the right direction. Thanks

So I want my query to return:

```
AAA   Lee, Albert      
BBB   Robert, Steven  
CCC   Jones, Albert   
DDD   Lim, Kevin       
EEE   Zhang, Wil
```

OR

```
AAA   Lee, Albert      12
BBB   Robert, Steven   4
CCC   Jones, Albert    3
DDD   Lim, Kevin       21
EEE   Zhang, Wil       11
```

From Using Sample Data:

```
CODE  NAME             Count

AAA   Lee, Albert      12
BBB   Robert, Steven   4
CCC   Robert, Steven   2
CCC   Jones, Albert    3
DDD   Lim, Kevin       21
EEE   Zhang, Wil       11
EEE   Wil Zhang        5
```

Comment: what database engine and version are you using?

Comment: please provide the RDBMS you are using and the SQL that you have tried so far

Comment: @Lamak Sorry I am using Microsoft Sql Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could LEFT JOIN the table to itself and filter the results

```
SELECT t1.* FROM Data AS t1
LEFT JOIN Data AS t2
ON
(t1.CODE = t2.CODE) AND (t1.Count < t2.Count)
WHERE t2.Count is null
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/cc2ea/4

Answer (score 1):

The standard SQL method uses the ANSI standard `row_number()` function:

```
select s.*
from (select s.*,
             row_number() over (partition by code order by count desc) as seqnum
      from sample s
     ) s
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Than you for you response, I'm still fairly new to SQL Server, i have been attempting to solve it with a subquery that can bring me the MAX(COUNT), do you know how to solve it with a HAVING clause?